# Condition for a block matrix to be positive semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, block-matrices

Let's say we have two positive semi-definite matrices $A$ and $B$ and a negative real $\lambda$. What would be the conditions for the matrix $M$, defined as follows, to be positive semi-definite too ?
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & \lambda I\\
\lambda I & B
\end{pmatrix},$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

I know that $M$ is positive semi-definite if and only if its Schur complement $S=A- \lambda^2 B$ is positive semi-definite, as it is stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement#Schur_complement_condition_for_positive_definiteness). But it doesn't help me much... Furthermore, I would like to find conditions which work also for block matrices with more than 2 blocks per row and columns like this one:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
A & \lambda_{1,2} I & \lambda_{1,3} I \\
\lambda_{1,2} I & B & \lambda_{2,3} I \\
\lambda_{1,3} I & \lambda_{2,3} I & C
\end{pmatrix},$$

Comment: If you didn't like the answer for the four block case, you won't like this answer for the nine-block case.  But you could go through the steps of the Cholesky Factorization algorithm, and obtain a pair of conditions like the one you had above (but one of the conditions would be rather more complicated to write down).